# Azure DevOps: An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Lately I've been trying to make an Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy to 3 environments, with 2 different data centers and 2 different service connections. I've been trying to achieve this with using as little lines of YAML as possible.

After a lot of trial and error, I'm stuck on this message "An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. An item with the same key has already been added."

deploy-env.yaml:

```
parameters:
  - name: OPENSHIFT_NAMESPACE
    displayName: 'OpenShift namespace'
    type: object
    values: []

  - name: DCR
    displayName: 'Data Center'
    type: object
    values: []

  - name: OSC
    displayName: 'Openshift service connection'
    type: object
    values: []

stages:
- ${{ each namespace in parameters.OPENSHIFT_NAMESPACE }}:
    - ${{ each dcr in parameters.DCR }}:
      - ${{ each osc in parameters.OSC }}:
        - stage: deploy-${{ convertToJson(namespace) }}
          jobs:
          - deployment: deploy_to_dcr
            environment: ${{ namespace }}
            displayName: 'Deploy to DCR1'
            strategy:
              runOnce:
                deploy:
                  steps:
                    - template: steps/deploy_to_cluster_with_helm_templating.yml@pipeline_templates
                      parameters:
                        DATA_CENTER: ${{ dcr }}
                        OPENSHIFT_NAMESPACE: ${{ namespace }}
                        OPENSHIFT_SERVICE_CONNECTION: '${{ osc }}'
                        HELM_VALUES:
                          - 'global.namespace=${{ namespace }}'
                          - 'global.data_center=${{ DCR }}'
```

azure-pipeline.yaml

```
  resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipeline_templates
      type: git
      name: pipeline-templates


stages:
  - template: deploy-env.yaml
    parameters:
      OPENSHIFT_NAMESPACE:
        - development
        - test
        - acceptance
      DCR:
        - dcr1
        - dcr2
      OSC:
        - OCP4DCR1
        - OCP4DCR2
```

Does anyone knows why this error occurs? I've found other articles where stage/job names we're not unique, but that is not the case in this example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably the use of the parameters `dcr` and `ocs` both as parameters and as iterator variables within your `each` statements.

Answer (score 4):

This line is getting repeated twelve times, with only four different values:

```
- stage: deploy-${{ convertToJson(namespace) }}
```

Stage names must be unique.